# Start and endblock function Reverted Transactions

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix, contract-debugging, ico

I am trying to create a function which allows users to only purchase tokens in between specific block numbers reverting all other transactions that try to purchase after or before theese block numbers, basically a timer which opens and closes purchasing, I came across the problem that the functions don't work, instead of letting me purchase in between the blocks, the contract  wont let me purchase at anytime the transaction always fails, (gets reverted) the ether never gets transferred and never even leaves my wallet. Testing on the Ropsten Testnet.

Comment: Are you testing this on a chain, where these block numbers are valid ? Because, in testRPC, for example, it won't be so, of course.

Comment: i am testing this on the ropsten testnet, and I always make sure the blocks are relevant, i change them all the time, and look at the currenct blocks via https://ropsten.etherscan.io/blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timestamp in ethereum is a seconds timestamp, amounts of seconds passed since epoch(01/01/1970). The time stamp you specified,i.e.,

```
uint public startBlock = 1516220;
uint public endBlock = 1516240;
```

gives value to startBlock as 18 Jan 1970 13:10:20 +0000 `and endBlock as`18 Jan 1970 13:10:40 +0000`. (At the point of writing the ans, the time stamp is 
1503356016 in seconds). So it's an issue of providing value.

You can specify the startBlock value as `now ()` which returns the timestamp of the current block.

Also in this line

```
uint tokens = safeDiv(safeMul(msg.value * 1.01 ether, getPrice()), 1000000000000000000 ether);
```

Msg.value gives the value in ether only,i.e., `value entered*10^18`. So writing msg.value* 1.01 ether is not required (also why 1.01 ether).

```
startBlock=block.timestamp
```

This will give the current timestamp to start block. For endblock, do

```
endBlock= startBlock + noOfSec
```

where `noOfSec` is the total no of seconds the crowdsale will run after starting

Comment: 1.01 ether, because I want the people to get 1 percent extra tokens for every ether, and also how do I find the time stamp? where can I find it, how do I know where to find the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
contract Crowdsale {
    uint public startBlock;
    uint public endBlock;

    uint public constant PRICE = 400;

    Crowdsale(uint _startBlock, uint _endBlock) {
        require(block.number < _startBlock);
        require(_startBlock < _endBlock);
    }

    function buy() payable {
        require(block.number >= startBlock && block.number <= endBlock);
        require(msg.value > 0);
        // Calculate tokens
        int tokens = msg.value * PRICE;
        balance[msg.sender] += tokens;
    }
}
```